# Microsoft Azure SDK 2.8.2 shows up as a product update after installing it

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Microsoft Azure SDK 2.8.2 shows up as a product update after installing it.  Just an annoyance, but it should clear from the updates list, anyone know how to clear it?

Answer (score 3):

I just happened to try again and they released 2.8.2.1, so if you install that you are good.